# how to subtract dictionary from dictionary with python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

Python 3 doesn't support this:

```
dict1  = {key1:6, key2:7, key3:5} 
dict2  = {key1:9, key2:3, key3:4} 
dict3 = dict1 - dict2
```

So how how can I subtract dictionary from dictionary in python 3?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `collections` module.

**Ex:**

```
from collections import Counter

dict1  = Counter({"key1":6, "key2":7, "key3":5}) 
dict2  = Counter({"key1":9, "key2":3, "key3":4})

dict1.subtract(dict2)
print(dict1)
```

**Output:**

```
Counter({'key2': 4, 'key3': 1, 'key1': -3})
```

Comment: This doesn't handle negative numbers! So weird (maybe expected though?). Cool solution.

Comment: Ahh, fixed it, awesome.

Comment: Please accept ans if it solved your problem(tick symbol under the upvote button). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can comprehend it:

```
>>> dict1 = {'key1':6, 'key2':7, 'key3':5} 
>>> dict2 = {'key1':9, 'key2':3, 'key3':4}
>>> dict3 = {key:dict1[key]-dict2[key] for key in dict1}
>>> dict3
{'key2': 4, 'key1': -3, 'key3': 1}
```

Of course I'm not handling errors:

1. Missing keys in dict 2 (`defaultdict` can solve)
2. Missing keys in dict 1 (maybe OK?)